# I want to save an Arraylist of objects into a file.Can Someone help me with this?

Tags: java

```
public void savemap (File file)
      { 
        if (file == null) {         
          if (chooser == null) chooser = createChooser();
          chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
          int r = chooser.showDialog(this, null);
          if (r != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return;
          file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }                           /* get the selected file */
        try {                       /* save the current TSP */
          FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
          writer.write();
          writer.close(); }
        catch (IOException e) {
          String msg = e.getMessage();
          this.stat.setText(msg); System.err.println(msg);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg,
            "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }                           /* set the status text */
        this.curr = file;           /* note the new file name */
      }
```

Edited

```
 try {
            int rows = 50;
            int columns = 50;
            Cell [][] cellArray = new Cell[columns][rows];

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            oos.writeObject(cellArray);
        }
```

//This is what i changed the code. Is it correct? However i have an error at (FILE_PATH)
FILE_PATH cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: `writer.write( )` Write what??

Comment: What is the problem? Where is the List?

Comment: got to admit...this is first time someone has shown the code and not explained what they want...generally its the otherway round!! :D

Comment: As @drewmore stated, you have called a write method, but not indicated what you want to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment: When you call `writer.write( )`, it expects you to give it a parameter that tells it *what* to write. Without that parameter, your code should not be compiling.

```
String s = "foobar"
writer.write(s)
```

or just:

```
writer.write("foobar")
```

will write a `String` value to file.

A second problem you have is that `FileWriter` (or more accurately, `Writer`, which it derives from) is only capable of writing `String`s, `char`s and `int`s by itself. If you want to write arbitrary Objects to file, you'll need to use an `ObjectOutputStream`:

```
RandomObject rando = new RandomObject(); 
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
oos.writeObject(rando);
```

You might find [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/) tutorial useful.

Comment: It is important to note that only objects that implement  the `Serializable` interface, can be written to file streams.

Comment: Sorry this is actually the first time i`m using stack overflow. My coding is kind of weak so pardon me please if i say stupid things but thanks for explaining to me how the write method work. I want to save a 2 dimension array something like this:

cellArray[columns][rows]

to the file writer. My project is requires me to save objects from a grid in java swing and im using this array to store my objects. How do i write it in the writer.write() if i want to save such an array?

Comment: `oos.writeObject(cellArray)`. This method can be used to write any object *or any array or collection of objects* - ***provided those objects implement the `Serializable` interface*** - an empty interface that simply tells Java that it's okay to *serialize* this object (which is what you're doing when you write it to file) You should google that and learn what it means.

Comment: @drewmore just to clarify does it mean that i can`t use a Filewriter to save arrays, i have to use object output stream to save the array? I have edited my code above. Could you help me check if i did it right please?

Comment: Eh... No, you can't use a `FileWriter` to write an array *of Objects*.  And yes, you do need to use an `ObjectOutputStream` to write *Objects* or arrays of Objects. But you're not using `ObjectOutputStream` *instead* of `FileWriter` - they operate on different levels. You're using `FileOutputStream` instead of `FileWriter`, so that you can stack an `ObjectOutputStream` on top of it (which you can't do with a `FileWriter`). You should really look into the differences between these things - these are important concepts to grasp.

Comment: @drewmore Sorry i dont quite understand how they operate on different levels. Could you maybe show an example between them and if there`s anything wrong with my edited code above.is it possible for u to help me edit the code and explain to me what is wrong? Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: a) stop saying sorry. b) if you really want to learn the underlying concepts here, the internet is full of great resources. c) If you just want to get your code working, I've already told you what you need to do: If you have any objects of custom classes in `cellArray`, make sure they implement `Serializable` (`class CustomClass implements Serializable` instead of just `class CustomClass`). Then, get rid of your `FileWriter`, create a new `FileOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` as shown above, and call `oos.writeObject(cellArray)`

Comment: ok i think i`ve roughly got the concept, will try googling to know more about the difference. I still don`t quite get why there is an error at the (FILE_PATH) code u gave though. FILE_PATH cannot be resolved to a variable